# Sql Developer ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I can't connect to my Sql Developer Version 4.1.3.20.

`lsnrctl status` shows successful with two instances showing status UNKOWN.
And I started the service `OracleServiceXE`
Whats wrong?

Hostname: localhost

Port: 1521

SID: xe

**listener.ora**

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER =   (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = PLSExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )   )

LISTENER =   (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    )   )

DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = (XE)
```

**tnsnames.ora**

```
XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )

EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = PLSExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA = 
  (DESCRIPTION = 
    (ADDRESS_LIST = 
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1)) 
    ) 
    (CONNECT_DATA = 
      (SID = CLRExtProc) 
      (PRESENTATION = RO) 
    ) 
  )
```

**lsnrctl status**

```
LSNRCTL for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on 31-MRZ-2016 18:11
:40

Copyright (c) 1991, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Produ
ction
Start Date                31-MRZ-2016 14:21:13
Uptime                    0 days 3 hr. 50 min. 47 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Default Service           XE
Listener Parameter File   C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\network\a
dmin\listener.ora
Listener Log File         C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\diag\tnslsnr\Robin-PC\listener\
alert\log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PIPENAME=\\.\pipe\EXTPROC1ipc)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=1521)))
Services Summary...
Service "CLRExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "CLRExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "PLSExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "PLSExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
```

Comment: Add the output of `lsnrctl status` command.

Comment: How is the connection defined in SQL Developer? From the error message you have told it to use a SID instead of a service name. (If you you were using a service name, or the TNS alias which uses a service name, the ORA-12505 would refer to 'service name' instead of 'SID').

Comment: @AlexPoole What informations do you need exactly? Where do i find them? My connection is Host: localhost Port: 1521 sid: xe.

Comment: Well, don't use a SID - you don't have the XE SID configured in the SID_LIST_LISTENER section. Change the connection setting radio button from 'SID' to 'Service name', and put XE in there instead. (Though that will still only work if the database is up and has registered with the listener)

Comment: your service summary doesn't list the XE service, just CLRExtProc and PLSExtProc. Is the windows XE service itself running? if so, try a bequeath connection in SQL Developer

Comment: @AlexPoole When i use service name, I get the following: I/O-Fehler: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection

Comment: @thatjeffsmith I dont find the service XE. How do i start it up or get it to work?

Comment: >>And I started the service OracleServiceXE
OK, so it's running. Can you connect with SQL*Plus? Can you try the bequeath connection option in SQLDev? Bequeath connects directly to oracle, bypasses the listener - avail when the db is running on your local machine

Comment: @thatjeffsmith I dont have SQL*Plus installed, but I can run SQL cmd

Comment: sqlplus is part of XE, it's there

Comment: @thatjeffsmith Found it! Sorry

Comment: @thatjeffsmith When i select local/bequeath, I get the following error: no ocijdbc12 in java.library.path